# Rails and HTML5: Making date_select dropdowns look better

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to get the drop downs for month and year to look like the input fields where they are thicker?

[image: form]

here's my rails code, it's part of a partial.  I used the form-control on the input fields but it looks like it doesn't work so well on those dropdowns.

```
<div class="new_cert"> 

  <div class="field">
    <%= ff.label :certification_name, 'Certification Title' %>
    <%= ff.text_field :certification_name, class: "form-control" %>       
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= ff.label :certification_authority %>
    <%= ff.text_field :certification_authority, class: "form-control" %>       
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= ff.label :certification_number %>
    <%= ff.text_field :certification_number, class: "form-control" %>       
  </div>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <div class="field">
        <%= ff.label :certification_from, "From" %><br />
        <%= ff.date_select :certification_from, :order => [:day, :month, :year],
            :start_year => Date.current.year, :end_year => 1960,
            :prompt => {day: 'Day', month: 'Month', year: 'Year'}, :discard_day => true, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>     
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
      <div class="field">
        <%= ff.label :certification_to, "To" %><br />
        <%= ff.date_select :certification_to, :order => [:day, :month, :year], 
            :start_year => Date.current.year + (10), :end_year => 1960,
            :prompt => {day: 'Day', month: 'Month', year: 'Year'}, :discard_day => true, class: 'form-control'  %>            
      </div>        
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>  

  <div>
    <%= ff.label :cert_never_expires, "This certification does not expire", class: "l" %>
    <%= ff.check_box :cert_never_expires, class: 'cb' %>
  </div>
  <br />

</div><!-- ./new_cert -->
```

here's the form

```
 <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for :achievements, Achievement.new do |ff| %>

      <!-- a partial is rendered based on the user dropdown selection -->    
      <div id="cert">
        <%= render partial: "achievements/new_certification", locals: { ff: ff } %>
      </div>

    <% end %><!-- fields_for -->

    <%= f.submit 'Save', id: "submit-achievement", class: 'btn btn-primary form-control' %>

  </div><!-- modal body -->

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>

  <% end %><!-- form_for -->
```

Comment: Have you tried adding additional classes to your select tags and increasing their padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got it figured out after reading over the API doc looks like date_select has `date_select(method, options = {}, html_options = {})`

so all I had to do was wrap the options part in ellipses {} like this

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= ff.label :certification_to, "To" %><br />
    <%= ff.date_select :certification_to, { :order => [:day, :month, :year], 
        :start_year => Date.current.year + (10), :end_year => 1960,
        :prompt => {day: 'Day', month: 'Month', year: 'Year'}, :discard_day => true }, class: 'form-control'  %>
  </div>
```

[image: after]

Answer (score 0):

There's a ton of things you can do. If you're just wanting the base select options to look like the other inputs with Bootstrap, then you are correct with the class of `form-control`. However, you need to use `input_html: { class: 'form-control' }` in your `ff.date_select` in order for the class to actually show up.

To get more in depth styling, try Select2: https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails

Comment: thanks, it's not working though.  I'm not using Simple_Form gem, not sure if that matters?  I've used class: form-control on other dropdowns without issue, not sure why the date_select doesn't seem to have it applied.

Comment: What form type are you using? Just a regular `form_for` or `semantic_form_for`? Have you tried wrapping the class like `html_options: {class: 'form-control'}`? That is another way to do it. The `date_select`, is it the generic rails date_select or did you customize it?

Comment: yes I tried adding html_options: {class: 'form-control'} like you suggested in place of class: 'form-control' but I'm getting the same result.  The date_select is not customized.  I added my form to teh above post if you want to check it out.  thanks